# Why Is toggle() Not Working?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got a jsFiddle working how I want: http://jsfiddle.net/6wuUc/64/

But for some reason, when I use the exact same code, I'm not getting the animation when I click the button. Here's the code I'm using on my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/style.css">

<script src="_/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
    $('.sv_play_button').toggle(function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '346'}, "fast");
    },function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '0'}, "fast");
    });​
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="video">
    <div class="sublime">
        <p class="sv_play_button">Click</p>
    </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#video, #video .sv_play_button {position: absolute;}

#video { margin-left: -346px; width: 670px; height: 546px; background-color: blue;}

.sublime { width: 1016px; height: 546px; background-color: red; opacity: 0.8; }

.sv_play_button {padding: 5px; background-color: yellow; top: 0px; right:0px; }​
```

Anyone got any idea why the toggle() isn't working on my page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem**

You haven't wrapped your jquery in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready) which is required to run any jquery events.

What is hapenning is that the javascript is attempting to run jquery code before jquery has even been loaded which is why you must wait until the document has loaded (with the use of `.ready()`).

Your new javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.sv_play_button').toggle(function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '346'}, "fast");
    },function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '0'}, "fast");
    });​
});
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that all your functions must be outside of this or they will not be callable. Also remember that this wrapper is a function so global variables must be defined outside of it.

if you don't have it referenced already, you will need to reference jquery in your head like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**References**

- [$(document).ready()](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)

Comment: Ok I must be doing something wrong. I've created a linked a functions.js file to my page and placed my jquery in a $(document).ready() block within the functions file. Still not working.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried putting before the closing body tag like you showed.

Comment: try putting it in your head after you've referenced the jquery file, (i've added this to the answer)

Comment: Still no dice dude. Should I upload the file?

Answer (score 3):

its not working because you have the script executing before the page is loaded.  When your script is running, the element you search for doesnt exist yet, so your jQuery selector doesnt find anything upon which to act.

wrap your function in a document ready block, and you should be all set.

```
jQuery(function(){
    your code here
})
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

<strike>toggle also doesnt support the way you're calling it.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/</strike>

You can't pass two functions (as far as I can tell), as toggle only shows or hides an element. EDIT: MagicDev points out the [toggle event api](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: actually .toggle *can* be used to do what he is trying to do aswell, read http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Thanks for the link @MagicDev.  Didn't know about that shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still can't get it to work. Any idea why?

Comment: seems to work for this http://jsfiddle.net/RWrQS/.   Something else must be impacting your script.

Comment: I've uploaded the file here: http://f.cl.ly/items/3z1u3v421P0V2B3w2u3b/index.html I can't seem to work out what might be impacting the script.

Comment: Simple... you have an illegal character in your script. `â€‹`  Chrome developer tools pointed this out *immediately*.  Open your script with notepad++, and Encode in UTF8.  Or retype your script.  Copy/paste in this scenario is bad.

Comment: Where is the illegal character coming from? I don't have notepad++, is there another way around this. Why is copy and pasting bad practice?

Comment: The illegal character can come from many places, and [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is free.  You can also retype your script in a *blank* file.  copy/paste (here) is bad, because you'll end up copying the invalid character again and again, and again, and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just move your script to the bottom of your page right above the `</body>` tag.

```
...
<script>
    $('.sv_play_button').toggle(function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '346'}, "fast");
    },function(){
        $('#video').animate({left: '0'}, "fast");
    });​
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wrapped your jquery in a $(document).ready() which is required to run any jquery events.